# SSRS Report Builder 15 pass parameter to subquery from count

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

Hi I have built an SSRS Report with the following expression =SUM(IIF(Fields!OurSplitYear.Value = Fields!TodaysSplitYear.Value AND Fields!NextDueDate.Value > Today(),1,0)) that basically counts if values are true for a line.  The line includes the PlaceReference as well as the above Field Values but isn't referred to in the Count.  The count looks at the NextDueDate as one parameter to tell me how many places are overdue.

So the table fetches a count of 9 places back as the total then the forumula changes slightly to fetch each month of the year.

If I click on 9 to take me to a sub report I want to see a list of the 9 places that are overdue, however it's only passing the very first PlaceReference.  I have multiple values selected on the SubReport Parameter and I have the same query that pulls the original data referring to the parameter.

Is it possible to pass the whole 9 Place References through to the SubReport instead of just the first one?  Many thanks.